# understanding haskell recursive code with init and last functions

Tags: haskell, recursion

```
bubblesort2 :: (Ord a, Show a) => [a] -> [a]
bubblesort2 [] = []
bubblesort2 [x] = [x]
bubblesort2 (x:y:rest) =
    bubblesort2 (init bubbled) ++ [last bubbled]
    where
        (first,second) = if x > y then (y,x) else (x,y)
        bubbled = first : bubblesort2(second:rest)
```

I'm trying to understand the below haskell code and had the following question:

In haskell code will the bubbled will be evaluated 2 times in the line one for init bubbled and other for last bubbled or evaluated only one time.

```
bubblesort2 (init bubbled) ++ [last bubbled]
```

Comment: These should be posted as 3 separate questions! Each of your numbered parts is entirely independent from the others. This way, it's hard for anyone to provide an adequate answer. See [this meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) for justification.

Comment: @Adam i tried to edit the below code but for some reason it is not properly formatthing how did you achieve proper formatting.

Comment: @Curious, honestly, I don't recall.. I think it was correct by the time I got to the question edit.  My main goal was to change "questions" to "question", and remove the bullet point you had (maybe that fixed it); since it looks like you've re/moved the other two questions per hnefatl's suggestion.

Comment: In the expression `bubblesort2 (init bubbled) ++ [last bubbled]`, you cannot  in general deduce whether `bubbled` is evaluated once or twice. The compiler is free to make either choice, because both choices give the same answer. In practice, GHC will produce code which evaluates `bubbled` twice. If you want to evaluate it once, write a function `initLast :: [a] -> Maybe ([a], a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bubbled` will only be evaluated once per call to `bubblesort2`.

Your `where` clause `bubbled = first : bubblesort2(second:rest)` defines `bubbled` and associates it with a [thunk](https://wiki.haskell.org/Thunk). This thunk is a stand-in for the value of `bubbled`.

If `bubbled`'s value is forced by the evaluation of `init bubbled` (or `last bubbled`), the thunk will be replaced by the forced value, which can be reused (without reevaluation) by `last bubbled` (or `init bubbled`).